# Edit Google Cloud Image Script

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-console

I am creating an instance in GCloud console:

New VM instance/Change the Boot Disk to "Debian GNU/Linux 9 Stretch + TF nightly-2-x" (or any GPU/deep learning boot disks)/add GPU

[image: GCloud new instance]

This image has multiple benefits, pre-install cuda and ... One benefit that I'm not interested in is that it starts a JupyterLab server as well.

My question is how can I edit the startup script that is starting the notebook? I want to remove that and edit the other parts. 
1) Where is the image script? 
2) How can I edit it before starting the VM?

EDIT) Apparently,Jupter even has a user for itself and runs as soon as the instance gets started. The question remains the same, where can I edit the script that is running the JupterLab

Comment: remove jupyter from the machine, snapshot your own image from the machine, and use that new image in the future.

Comment: it starts jupyter from a specific user, in general. I'm more interested in changing the behaviour of the whole startup script. Somewhere is calling Jupyter and other things to start, where is it?

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no option to change anything in the public image google provided for customer but as [@Travis Webb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/291180/travis-webb) suggested, you can follow below steps:

- Start a vm with one [public image](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images#os-compute-support) (one time work)
- Modify as per your requirement (also one time work)
- Create a [custom image](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images#custom_images) following the steps of [the document](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/create-delete-deprecate-private-images#create_image)
- then use that custom image for further use

NOTE: I do not have enough rep to comment thus posting as answer. please feel free to let me know if I need to add/modify/delete